# Replacing "foreach" with "for" in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to replace my "foreach" with "for", but actually I don't know how. 
Here is the part of my php code:

```
$r = "";
$j = 0;
foreach ($orgs as $k => $v) {
    echo "\n\r" . $v->id . "\n\r";
    if (1) {
        $a_view_modl = ArticleView :: model($v->id, $v->id);
        $connection = $a_view_modl->getDbConnection();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: why does this need to be a for loop? you can still increment variable on each iteration of a foreach loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [How 'foreach' actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$r = "";
$j = 0;
foreach ($orgs as $k => $v) {
    echo "\n\r" . $v->id . "\n\r";
    if (1) {  //you don't really need this, because it's allways true
        $a_view_modl = ArticleView :: model($v->id, $v->id);
        $connection = $a_view_modl->getDbConnection();
```

if `$orgs` is an associative array, it becomes:

```
$r = "";
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($orgs); $i++)
{
    echo "\n\r" . $orgs[$i]->id . "\n\r";
    $a_view_modl = ArticleView :: model($orgs[$i]->id, $orgs[$i]->id);
    $connection = $a_view_modl->getDbConnection();
}
```

better you do some checks first if you go for this solution.

if you implement your solution with `foreach` which is in this case more readable, you can increment or decrement a given variable, like normal:

```
$i++; //if you want the increment afterwards
++$i; //if you want the increment before you read your variable
```

the same for decrements:

```
$i--; //decrement after reading the variable
--$i; //decrement before you read the variable
```

Comment: lets just hope that $orgs is not an associative array

Comment: @andrew, I totally agree with you. but since he wanted to have a for loop, I thought he should know what he wants to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` loop is just a better readable `for` loop. It accepts an array and stores the current key (which is in this case an index) into `$k` and the value into `$v`.
Then `$v` has the value you are using in the snippet of code.
A for loop does only accept indexed arrays, and no associative arrays.

We can rewrite the code by replacing `$v` with `$orgs[ index ]`, where index starts from 0.

```
$r = "";
$j = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($orgs); $i++) {
    echo "\n\r" . $orgs[$i]->id . "\n\r";
    if (1) {
        $a_view_modl = ArticleView::model($orgs[$i]->id, $orgs[$i]->id);
        $connection = $a_view_modl->getDbConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = "";
$j = 0;
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($orgs); $i++)
{
    $v = $orgs[$i];
    echo "\n\r" . $v->id . "\n\r";
    if (1) {
        $a_view_modl = ArticleView :: model($v->id, $v->id);
        $connection = $a_view_modl->getDbConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($orgs as $k => $v) {
    // Your stuff
}
```

for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orgs); $i++) {
    // Your stuff ... use $orgs[$i];
}
```